# Flutter: Adding a custom dialog to Text

Tags: flutter, customdialog

I am trying to create a Custom dialog when the text is clicked. but dialog is not creating.
below adding the Dialog box implementation code

```
         child: new Center(
                child: new RichText(
                  text: new TextSpan(
                    children: [
                      new TextSpan(
                        text: 'Accept the ',
                        style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      new TextSpan(
                        text: 'Terms & Conditions',
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
                          ..onTap = () {
                               CustomDialogBox(
                                title: "Custom Dialog Demo",
                                descriptions: "Hii all this is a custom dialog in flutter and  you will be use in your flutter applications",
                                text: "Yes",
                              );
                          },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

adding Custom Dialog Code. creating as new widget in new dart page and importing in the application.
we need it as a widget which we can use many times in the app.
so creating in a new dart page.

```
class CustomDialogBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title, descriptions, text;
  final Image img;

  const CustomDialogBox({Key key, this.title, this.descriptions, this.text, this.img}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomDialogBoxState createState() => _CustomDialogBoxState();
}

class _CustomDialogBoxState extends State<CustomDialogBox> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Constants.padding),
      ),
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: contentBox(context),
    );
  }
  contentBox(context){
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: Constants.padding,top: Constants.avatarRadius
              + Constants.padding, right: Constants.padding,bottom: Constants.padding
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: Constants.avatarRadius),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Constants.padding),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(color: Colors.black,offset: Offset(0,10),
                    blurRadius: 10
                ),
              ]
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(widget.title,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),),
              SizedBox(height: 15,),
              Text(widget.descriptions,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
              SizedBox(height: 22,),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: Text(widget.text,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need wrap 'CustomDialogBox' with 'showDialog()' widget.

```
  child: new Center(
                child: new RichText(
                  text: new TextSpan(
                    children: [
                      new TextSpan(
                        text: 'Accept the ',
                        style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      new TextSpan(
                        text: 'Terms & Conditions',
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
                          ..onTap = () {
                               showDialog(
                                   context: context,
                                   builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                       return CustomDialogBox(
                                           title: "Custom Dialog Demo",
                                           descriptions: "Hii all this is a custom dialog in flutter and  you will be use in your flutter applications",
                                            text: "Yes",
                                        );
                                   }
                               );
                          },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with CustomDialogBox ... your onTap method is incorrect in the question posted.

You should do

```dart
showDialog(
           context: context,
           builder: (BuildContext context) => CustomDialogBox(),
)
```